# How do I read an XML file outside of a jar?

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to get the jar to read from target/classes outside of the jar so I can configure the data easier than going in the jar. The below is what I'm using to read the file, but it's reading from within the jar. After reading the XML I'm using DocumentBuilder to parse the XML.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
InputStream configFile = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(file);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The below is what I'm using to read the file, but it's reading from
>   within the jar.

To read a resource outside the jar that you execute, don't use classloader to find the resource that will looks for in the running jar but use `File` or better `Path` that allows to locate/manipulate resources in a filesystem.
You could just do it :

```
InputStream configFile =  Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(file));
```

Whatever, I am not sure that you use case be valid as reading a file from `target/classes` makes not really sense as resources located at this place are not designed to be persistent but to be packaged in the built artifact (here a JAR).